# What is the intuition (geometric picture) of Bianchi's identity

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-bundles, curvature, connections

The Bianchi's identity reads

$\textrm{d}\Omega = \Omega \wedge \omega - \omega\wedge \Omega$,

where $\Omega$ is the curvature 2-form, $\omega$ is the connection 1-form.

Is there an intuitive picture that we can draw for this identity?

Comment: The Bianchi identity says that the curvature $2$-form is covariantly constant. If $\nabla$ is a connection and $d_\nabla:\Omega^k(X,\text{End}(E))\to\Omega^{k+1}(X,\text{End}(E))$ is the induced connection on the endomorphism bundle, the Bianchi identity can be written as $d_\nabla F_\nabla=0$.

Comment: Thank you; any references for this? translate this to plain English for a poor physicist?

Comment: what is $F_\nabla$?

Comment: $F_\nabla$ is the curvature $2$-form of a connection $\nabla$ - this is vector bundle notation. You use $\omega$ and $\Omega$ which is typically used for principal bundles, but a very similar statement holds. See L. Tu's "Differential Geometry" or M. Hamilton's "Mathematical Gauge Theory".

Comment: So something covariantly constant means if we parallel transport it it stays the same (the parallel transported version and itself at the new location are always the same). Geometrically/intuitively why is this true?

Comment: Not everything has an intuitive explanation, and I don't have one for you. Given the local connection $1$-form $A$, we have $F=dA+\frac{1}{2}[A,A]$. You can check that $d_\nabla$ acts as $d_\nabla\eta=d\eta+[A,\eta]$. Hence, $d_\nabla F_\nabla=\frac{1}{2}d[A,A]+[A,dA]+\frac{1}{2}[A,[A,A]]$. Now, you can check that $[A,[A,A]]=0$, and the other two terms cancel each other out.